# Can't make purchases on opencart website from android webview

Tags: php, android, android-webview, opencart, e-commerce

I need help with my Android app for Speedway Groceries. The app was created using a `WebView` that displays the website within the app. However, It seems as if no one can make a purchases through the app. What happens is that after a user navigates to the shopping cart and proceeds to checkout, all of the checkout fields are not showing. On some devices it shows a warning message

> "Security headers is not vaild"

[attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSvMv.jpg)

Here is the code from java `MainActivity` class.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
         webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.speedwaygroceries.com/");
        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    }
```

Comment: Try this: `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` and `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(true);`

Comment: The Cookie manager didn't work. Its still doing the same thing. I just want to know why this is happening. It may have something to do with a security protocol in android or something. I wonder if it is something I can bypass.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following:

```
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); // replace settings with what matches your code
```

This will enable the checkout drop down menu as it uses web storage and the above API covers that.